# Yii2 validation rule for multiple inputs with same name

Tags: yii2

I have one form which has multiple inputs with same name which are dynamically added using jQuery. Input names are as below:

```
ModelName[dynamic_name][]
ModelName[dynamic_name][]
```

I have also declared `dynamic_name` as public variable in a `Model`. How can I validate the above inputs using yii2 validation rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `dynamic_name` variable will be an array of input values, you can use the new [`each`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.4/framework/validators/EachValidator.php) validator. It was added in v2.0.4. It takes an array and passes each element into another validator.

For example, to check if each element is an integer:

```
[['dynamic_name'], 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
```

Comment: Thanks.
Your code works fine if these kind of multiple inputs already exist in a form but when I add new inputs using jQuery in a form then it does not work.
So please can you assist me for that ?

Comment: Are you validating via Ajax?

Comment: No because if I do enableAjaxValidation true then other validation does not work

Comment: What do you mean by other validation?

Comment: Other validation means to validate other inputs except this dynamic input.

Comment: If I print $midel->errors then I am getting error messages respective to this dynamic inputs  but error messages are not show in HTML form without using Ajax Validation

Comment: Hmm. This changes your question entirely. Ask a new question with these details. Also include the code for your view and the javascript for creating the inputs in the question. That way someone who doesn't have to be me can answer the question.

Comment: @topher ,yes i am stuck in same situation and i am validation through ajax ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286133/yii2-add-dynamic-form-fields-and-their-validations

Answer (score 2):

yii2,  you can use with **`Class yii\validators\EachValidator`**

**VIEW**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'dynamic_name[]')->textInput() ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn', 'name' => 'hash-button']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**MODEL**

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
  public $dynamic_name = [];
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
        // checks if every dynamic_name is an integer
        ['dynamic_name', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
    ]
 }
}
```

> **Note**: This validator will not work with inline validation rules in case of usage outside the model scope, e.g. via validate() method.

Link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-eachvalidator.html